# NSDatePicker allows moving forward in time but not backward

Tags: cocoa, timezone, nscalendar, nsdatepicker

I am using an `NSDatePicker` in calendar format, which should give me the opportunity to move forward and backward through the months by using the little arrowheads.

In my case, I can *only* move forward in time. The 'left' arrow does not do anything. The minimum date is set to something in the past (year 2010), the maximum date to the future (2040), and the picker is initialized with today's date. It should really allow me to move backward. Why is this not happening?

Comment: It looks like setting minimum and maximum dates in the IB has something to do with it. The picker works when I don't use them!